# Which one better for XML data Mongodb or orientdb

Tags: java, xml, mongodb, orientdb, database

I cannot use an XML base database.
Have to choose from mongo DB or orient DB.
Which one will be more suitable for XML based data.
where I can directly save or fetch XMLs, run xpath, jquery.

Comment: Neither hasn't got any functionality whatsoever for treating XML as more than a string, so its really down to personal preference. However, [good old mySQL does](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html).

Comment: Why can you not use an XML database, if your requirement is to store XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB and OrientDB both store data in a JSON (like) data structure. JSON is **not** compatible with XML (only for simple use cases, where XML is used in a data centric way). So both are not suitable for native storage of XML. You can store the document as CLOB/BLOB. However, in that case a RDMBS or key-value store is also a good fit.

If you need to query the XML data (by using XQuery and/or XPath) your really should use a XML database. Highly recommended: [basex](http://basex.org/) and [existdb](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/homepage/index.html) (both are Java based, same as OrientDB).